# How to show a random array of char in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm currently busy writing a math programme/game.

I am using three labels namely:

`lblNum1` and `lblNum2` = Shows random number between 0 and 13

`lblOpp` = Shows random operator [+, -, ×, ÷]

I'm struggling to find a code on how my `lblOpp` can generate a random char from the list `[+, -, ×, ÷]`

I put the operators in an array 'operator : `array[1..4]` of `char`;' 
It was easy to display the numbers on random, since the random function only works with integers. I just don't know how to display my array values on random. 
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since your character values are in an array, simply generate a random number between 1..4 and use that as an index into your array.

```
const
  operator : array[1..4] of char = ('+', '-', '×', '÷');

lblNum1.Caption := IntToStr(Random(14));
lblNum2.Caption := IntToStr(Random(14));
lblOpp.Caption := operator[1 + Random(4)];
```

Comment: Or perhaps use string for storing operators characters instead of array of char.

Comment: Whether you use a string or an array, the concept is the same. Generate a random index, then use that to access the character from whatever container you choose to use.